# No control over screen brightness on Ubuntu-Mate 16.04

Tags: 14.04, brightness, samsung, mate

I'm running Ubuntu MATE on a samsung N210 netbook, which is rather old. I had it running Ubuntu 14.04, till yesterday, and the screen brightness control worked fine since day one.

After installing Ubuntu-MATE (from the the ubuntu-mate iso) the screen brightness is permanently at 100%, the fn combo works, and the overlay shows the brightness level being altered, but no actual change occurs. The same thing happens when altering from Power Management.

Any ideas?

Comment: Running into the same problem with my Samsung R580. I guess you have to hope for this project: https://answers.launchpad.net/samsung-tools/+question/289901

Answer (score 2):

Open `/etc/default/grub` with:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Modify the line reading `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

so it says

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=native"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```